# SQL login status disabled

Tags: sql-server, security, authentication

I made a mistake and disabled from SQL, in the Login Properties, at Status, the "Login".  A screen shot is more suggestive: [image]

Now I can not connect to the server. The eror is like:[image]

Has anyone any idea how to fix this?

Comment: login as another user with enough permission and go back to the same place and "enable" the user.

Comment: Log in as sysadmin (sa if someone on your team has it) and re enable it.

Comment: I do not have any other created user, what can I do then?